# how to merge two dict in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dict struct such like this:

```
a = {'1' : {}, '2' : {}} 

b = {'3' : 3, '4' : 4}
```

I want to have the following format:

```
a = {'1' : { '3' : 3 }, '2' : { '4' : 4 } }
```

I have tried many times, but I always get lost, could anybody help me?

Comment: Have you tried googling this?

Comment: Yes , I do, but not be useful, can you give me some suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works but what's the use case? Seems like there probably is a more elegant solution.

```
a = {i:{j:k} for i,(j,k) in zip(a.keys(),b.items())}
```

Comment: [Read the documentation on built-ins like `dict()`.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html) And click the checkmark to accept an answer!

Comment: It does not workd, see@Jal

Comment: It solves the problem you presented. It's just not a good way of doing these things generally. That's why I asked for the use case!

Comment: Sorry , it solves the prolem i presented, the use case is that I want to sort 'a in terms of some 'key' in 'a', and get some useful information. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

```
c = {i:{j:k} for i, (j, k) in zip(a.keys(), b.items())}

>>> c
{'2': {'3': 3}, '1': {'4': 4}}
```

There is no order in a dictionnary so you can't ensure that {3:3} or {4:4} is the value of key '1' or "2'